# Make Component in GridBagLayout take up same width

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

How to make Component in `GridBagLayout` take up same width? I have tried `GridBagConstraint.weightx`, but it doesn't work.

[image]

```
static void test3() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(480, 360);
    Container pane = f.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    String[] a = {
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "consectetur adipisicing",
            "elit, ",
            "sed do",
            "eiusmod",
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = i % 3;
        c.gridy = i / 3;
        c.weightx = 0.5;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        f.add(new JButton(a[i]), c);
    }
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 static void test3() {
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setSize(800, 360);
    Container pane = f.getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

    String[] a = {
            "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
            "consectetur adipisicing",
            "elit,",
            "sed do",
            "eiusmod",
    };
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        JButton test=new JButton(a[i]);
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridx = i %3;
        c.gridy = i /3;
        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,25));
        f.add(test, c);
    }
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

You need to set a preferred size for the buttons. this will give you desired outcome

Comment: `test.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(250,25));` Magic numbers, no more than a guess at the required size. See also [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)

Comment: it was just a quick test you can surely replace the numbers with variables if you really want to. if he wants to stay at gridbaglayout thats the solution otherwise eh can use formlayout

Answer (score 2):

Use a `GridLayout` for that section of the view. It will make the buttons all the same size, and assign as much height as needed for the tallest component, and as much width as needed for the widest.

> I have tried `GridBagConstraint.weightx`, but it doesn't work.

The `weightx` constraint has more to do with how to assign *extra* width or height when the GUI is resized, but the cell will start with the minimum height/width it needs for that row/column.